# Compare each row with one another in a dataset in R

Tags: r, dataset, row

My dataset has 377 rows and I want to comapare each row with all the other rows in the dataset and if two rows are completely equal then print a message.

```
for (i in 1:377)
{
for (j in 2:377)
  {
       if(row[i]== row[j])
        {
       print("Matched")

        }
      else j=j+1
  }

i=i+1
```

}

This is the simple algorithm of the situation. I am very new to R so I have problem in writing code so this algorithm might help you people in answering. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) along with the expected output

Comment: Probably this `DF$HasADupe <- duplicated(DF) | rev(duplicated(DF[rev(seq_len(nrow(DF))),]))` could help you, but it depends on your actual needs

Comment: @digEmAll could you please elaborate more ?

Comment: @ShahzaibAhmed: check my answer

Comment: @digEmAll Thanks man . It worked.

Comment: @digEmAll is there any way that if these rows have difference of 5 or less, It get marked similar? My dataset has all numeric values Thanks

Comment: Well, not using duplicated function... you should use a for-loop and just add a condition like `abs(row[i]-row[j]) < 5`, check my edited anser

Comment: @digEmAll actually I am trying to detect accident from a video dataset.  I have information related to frame number,  object,  mid point of x, mid point of y. Can you help me in this case.

Comment: Well, I suggest you to open a new question and provide more detailed information along with a small input example and expected output

Comment: I have posted a new question. Please can you help me in that.

Answer (score 1):

```
DF <- data.frame(A=c(1,3,2,1,4,3,3),B=c('A','X','B','A','X','X','Y'))

# example input
# > DF
#   A B
# 1 1 A
# 2 3 X
# 3 2 B
# 4 1 A
# 5 4 X
# 6 3 X
# 7 3 Y

# find which row indexes have duplicates
rowIndexesWithDupe <- which( duplicated(DF) | rev(duplicated(DF[rev(seq_len(nrow(DF))),])) )

# print
if(length(rowIndexesWithDupe) > 0){
  print(paste('Rows:',toString(rowIndexesWithDupe),'have duplicates'))
}else{
  print('No duplicates')
}

# output in this case : 
[1] "Rows: 1, 2, 4, 6 have duplicates"
```

**EDIT :**

As per comment, to check "almost duplicates" (e.g. within difference <= 5) you could use a for loop
(N.B.: we're assuming all values are numeric !):

```
DF <- data.frame(A=c(1,3,2,10,9,3,3),b=c(10,12,13,16,11,9,8))

# example input
# > DF
#    A  b
# 1  1 10
# 2  3 12
# 3  2 13
# 4 10 16
# 5  9 11
# 6  3  9
# 7  3  8

toler <- 5
dupes <- integer()
for(i in 1:(nrow(DF)-1)){
  row1 <- DF[i,]
  for(j in (i+1):nrow(DF)){
    row2 <- DF[j,]
    if(all(abs(row1-row2) <= toler)){
      dupes <- c(dupes,i,j)
    }
  }
}
dupes <- sort(unique(dupes))
print(paste('Rows:',toString(dupes),'have duplicates within tolerance =',toler))

# output in this case :
[1] "Rows: 1, 2, 3, 6, 7 have duplicates within tolerance = 5"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `anyDuplicated`:

```
DF <- data.frame(c(1,3,2,1,4,3,3), c('A','X','B','A','X','X','Y'))

if (anyDuplicated(DF)) print('Matched')
# [1] "Matched"
```